# Make defer prerequisite expansion until after target expansion

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Edit I expanded the Makefile.

Take the following makefile:

```
VERILATOR:=/usr/sbin/verilator
COMMONPREPARAMS:=-Wall
COMMONPOSTPARAMS:=--trace

# Multishot timer
MULTISHOT_TIMER_OBJDIR:=multishot_timer_dir
MULITSHOT_TIMER_VERILOG_FILES:=common/multishot_timer_tb.v common/multishot_timer.v
MULITSHOT_TIMER_TOPLEVEL:=multishot_timer_top.cpp
MULTISHOT_TIMER_TARGET:=$(MULTISHOT_TIMER_OBJDIR)/multishot

#incrementer
INCREMENTER_OBJDIR:=incrementer_dir
INCREMENTER_VERILOG_FILES:=common/incrementer.v
INCREMENTER_TOPLEVEL:=src/incrementer_top.cpp
INCREMENTER_TARGET:=$(INCREMENTER_OBJDIR)/incrementer

ALLTARGETS := $(MULTISHOT_TIMER_TARGET)
ALLOBJDIRS := $(MULTISHOT_TIMER_OBJDIR)

.PHONY: all multishot_timer incrementer

all: multishot_timer incrementer

multishot_timer: OBJDIR:=$(MULTISHOT_TIMER_OBJDIR)
multishot_timer: VERILOG_FILES:=$(MULITSHOT_TIMER_VERILOG_FILES)
multishot_timer: TOPLEVEL:=$(MULITSHOT_TIMER_TOPLEVEL)
multishot_timer: $(MULTISHOT_TIMER_TARGET)

incrementer: OBJDIR:=$(INCREMENTER_OBJDIR)
incrementer: VERILOG_FILES:=$(INCREMENTER_VERILOG_FILES)
incrementer: TOPLEVEL:=$(INCREMENTER_TOPLEVEL)
incrementer: $(INCREMENTER_TARGET)

$(ALLTARGETS): $(TOPLEVEL) $(VERILOG_FILES)
    $(VERILATOR) $(COMMONPREPARAMS) -cc $(VERILOG_FILES) --exe $(TOPLEVEL) -o $@
```

My actual problem is that the prerequisites of $(ALLTARGETS) is evaluated too early so that the rule never has any prerequisites.

What I want to to defer the evaluation of the prerequisites of the ALLTARGETS rule until after the evaluation of the target prerequisites, because that is the point where variables such as $(TOPLEVEL) are declared. Moreover, I want to be able to type all and then start multiple different targets, each with its own variables like $(TOPLEVEL).

A way to do this would be to create a new rule for every target in $(ALLTARGETS), but since the work for every target is exactly the same, I would like to do it with only one target. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You seem confused. I am confused.

```
multishot_timer: TOPLEVEL := $(MULITSHOT_TIMER_TOPLEVEL)
```

This is a *target-specific* variable.
`${TOPLEVEL}` will only have the value `multishot_timer_top.cpp` when *make* is expanding the recipe for `multishot_timer`, or the recipes *for any of its pre-requisites*. This is not the case when *make* expands this line:

```
$(ALLTARGETS): $(TOPLEVEL) $(VERILOG_FILES)
```

Fix? Simply make `TOPLEVEL` an ordinary global variable.

```
TOPLEVEL := $(MULITSHOT_TIMER_TOPLEVEL)
```

Methinks though that you have a larger pattern that you are not telling us about.

### Edit

OK. Two things to manage.

#### Dependencies

A target can have many dependency lines, but only one of them can have a recipe.

```
multishot_timer: common/multishot_timer_tb.v common/multishot_timer.v
incrementer: common/incrementer.v

multishot_timer incrementer:
    ${VERILATOR} ${COMMONPREPARAMS} -cc $^ --exe ${TOPLEVEL} -o $@
```

#### Changing the recipe depending on target

Many options here. Here's a suggestion for the problem at hand:

Basically  `${TOPLEVEL}` is different depending on whether `$@` is `multishot_timer` or `incrementer`.

```
TOPLEVEL<multishot_timer> := multishot_timer_top.cpp
TOPLEVEL<incrementer> := src/incrementer_top.cpp
TOPLEVEL = ${TOPLEVEL<$@>}
```

Nice. Probably not worth defining `TOPLEVEL` (notice that `=`, it's important that it's a lazy variable), and just use `${TOPLEVEL<$@>}` directly in the recipe.

#### For extra points: the list of targets

Get all the variable names of the form `TOPLEVEL<%>`, and remove the `TOPLEVEL<` prefix and `>` suffix.

```
ALLTARGETS := $(patsubst TOPLEVEL<%>,%,$(filter TOPLEVEL<%>,${.VARIABLES}))
```

(Notice how I reserve `${…}` for variables, and `$(…)` for functions. I find it helps. YMMV.)

Comment: I made the example in the OP bigger to further explain what I mean, but basically: I have many different possible setups, each with another value for the significant variables, but all of them with the same general rules for creating the executable.

Comment: I tried implementing this, but I seem to have done something wrong or misunderstood. I can not get the final rule to expand the variables properly. Can you give a more elaborate example?

Comment: Two hints: Run _make_ with `--warn-undefined-variables` and study the output. Also note that you must use `=` and `:=` correctly. They are _not_ the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you're using GNU make, with [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html).

In your example, you would use:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(ALLTARGETS): $$(TOPLEVEL) $$(VERILOG_FILES)
```

Note the extra `$` escaping in the prerequisites list.